# VueJS programmatically trigger update on watched variable

Tags: vue.js

Suppose I have a watcher that is watching an array `mylist`

```
watch {
 mylist:function(){
    //Code
 }
}
```

How can I programatically trigger an update on the variable and run the code (if the variable is unchanged)? How can I trigger an update if the watched variable is a nested object/array or a simple string?

Comment: Please provide some details about why you want to do it this way, maybe there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Since you didn't provide any description regarding the actual use-case, the best you can probably do is to extract a method that is called in call this method manually.

```
data: function() {
   return { myList: [] }
},

watch: {
   myList: this.handleListChange
},

methods: {
   handleListChange: function(a, b) {
       // .. do whatever you want to do in the watch method
   }
}
```

To trigger the "watch" method you can now simply call your **handleListChange** method manually.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 questions:

> How can I programatically trigger an update on the variable and run the code if the variable is unchanged?

You can hack it this way:

```
this._watchers.find(w => w.expression === "mylist").cb(this.mylist);
```

However, it's not part of the official [Vue API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/). The `_watchers` list is rather an implementation detail. It may change in the future without any notice.

---

> How can I trigger an update if the watched variable is a nested object/array?

Use a deep watcher:

```
watch: {
  mylist: {
    handler: function(val) {
      // Code
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

---

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/zjagahq2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i did it
Frank was on to something, i just couldn't access the "this" context like suggested
 so all had to do was pass all the args to the method.

```
watch: {
   myList: (...args) { this.handleListChange(...args) },
}
```